# Max width and Max length of a polygon?

Tags: arcpy

Is there a way to calculate the max width and length of a polygon or polygons? I'm currently working with roughly 10K+ building interior layouts. What I'm trying to do is generate and populate an SQL/Access database (only because it was requested) containing all of the data that I can pull from each floor plan/room. One of the requests that I received was to include the maximum length, width, and if available the height for each room within the data. I have performed various searches and have found solutions for calculating the average length/width, but I have yet to find a solution for calculating the maximum length/width.

Comment: If you can assume that the rooms are rectangular, and aligned with a common grid, then you could just intersect a number of horizontal and vertical arcs across the footprint, and choose the longest ones.

Comment: Unfortunately every room is a different size, shape, and orientation.

Comment: Size and shape are inconsequential; orientation is your pain point.

Comment: Look at the Illustration's Polygon Input, Rectangle_by_Width example on this page: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm. Would the dimensions of the resulting rectangle be what you're looking for? As for height, if it's not already in the data in some way, then I don't see how you could possibly derive it.

Comment: I wonder if you could use Toms suggestion to get the rectangle by width, then rotate the polygon so the the long axis of rectangle is along an x or y axis and then use some sort of Arc intersection as Vince suggests.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcPy but do not mention in your question whether you are using it.

Comment: TOM - this solution looks like it will work just fine. not sure why I have not come across this sooner.

Comment: PolyGeo - I will be using Python to access and process all of the polygons within the floor plans. the ArcPy module will be essential within the Python script in order to place the polygon in an acceptable format for me to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BoundingContainersSept28_2011](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=564e2949763943e3b9fb4240bab0ca2f)
Here is a great tool called Bounding Containers, from Dan Patterson, originally from Whuber, located on ESRI Arcscripts site. This only accepts Shapefile as input. I had to disable Background Processing.
As you can see from the screen shot, ShortAxis and LongAxis are the width and length dimensions of each rectangle produced.[image]